# Appium. Mobile App Automation. Wait until

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium, wait

Friends, please help!

I don't know how to do "wait.until".

I'm using Appium with UIAutomator.

My test would wait until new app's page will loaded and 'Text 1' in text field will be checked.

I have such parameters in UIAutomator:

```
text : Text 1;

recource-id: payment_content_title;

class: android.widget.TextView;

package: ru.mts.stm.mobilemts;
```

IntelliJ says that my code is incorrect:

```
WebDriverWait wait;
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBe(new MobileBy.ByAndroidUIAutomator(text),"Text 1"));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code for wait.

```
 WebDriverWait wait;
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("put id here")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use following method for the same :

```
 public MobileElement waitForElement(AppiumDriver<?> appiumDriver, MobileElement element) {
    webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(appiumDriver, 15);
    webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
    return element;
}
```