# Calling 'it' method after condition is met in Jasmine

Tags: jasmine

I recently started doing automation tests for iOS using Appium and Jasmine.

```
it('should add product to cart', () => {
    driver.pause(1000);
    $("~ProductDetailCTAView.addToCartButton").click();
    driver.pause(3000);
});

it('should see elements when clicked on the cart button', () => {
    $("~UIBarButtonItem.shopBarButton").click();
    $("~CartController.CartCell.0");
    driver.pause(3000);
});
```

What I want to do is, call these methods if addToCartButton is enabled. I tried putting them in an if condition but it says I can't put 'it' methods inside if-else conditions. I looked for asynchronous testing in Jasmine on internet but got confused.

Comment: I think you need a `waitUntil` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45237474/appium-mobile-app-automation-wait-until. I am not familiar with Appium though.

Comment: Don't miss to know when that button should be enabled and when that should be disabled exactly. After that, how about the define for any event on jasmine associated to that task correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You really can't put an 'IF' on Jasmine unit testing 'it' ,

If you need to test different paths of your code, you should write an entire 'it' to it.